# How to represent optionality and 0 or more in Prolog rules?

Tags: prolog, grammar, rule, bnf, dcg

I am trying to write a rule in order to represent 0 or more using recursion: The rule in EBNF is the following:

```
translation_unit 
        => external_declaration  { external_declaration}
```

My guess is the following:

```
translation_unit(Xs0,Xs) :-                         
         [external_declaration|Xs].
```

Also I would like to represent optionality in another rule which is the following:

```
declaration_specifiers_next
  a.    : ε
  b.    | declaration_specifiers
```

My guess would be:

```
  declaration_specifiers_next(Xs0, Xs)
        :- ε,
           [declaration_specifiers|Xs]
```

I am also confused about the argument that we give to the title of the rule in that case: `(Xs0, Xs)` What do they actually mean?

Comment: What do mean by "My guess would be"? Are you trying to create a program by typing symbols at random? How do you want to implement `translation_unit(Xs0, Xs)` if you haven't even defined what the meaning of `(Xs0, Xs)` is? It's your program, if you don't know what you want it to do, how is anyone else supposed to know that?

Comment: `ε, [declaration_specifiers|Xs]` isn't right since `,` represents an conjunction in Prolog, not disjunction that your BNF suggests. Also, a list by itself `[declaration_specifiers|Xs]` isn't a valid Prolog query. Are you familiar with the basics of Prolog? You probably want to study it a bit rather than guess. ;) For something like this, a DCG would be ideal: `declaration_specifiers_next --> [] | declaration_specifiers.` and `declaration_specifiers -->...`.

Answer (score 1):

The body of your first clause is a list and this is taken by Prolog systems as being a call to the predefined predicate `consult` used to open files and loading their contents as programs. This is not what you want...

The head of the clause seems to indicate you want to have a predicate for each non-terminal (class name) of the EBNF. If that is the case you probably want the predicate to have a clause for each possible alternative, you should convert your EBNF rule to context-free grammar rules like

```
translation_unit -> ε
translation_unit -> external_declaration translation_unit
```

and then write appropriate clauses in Prolog for your predicate.

In order to understand what is confusing you, you must first explain what you mean by *rule*. Is it a Definite-Clause Grammar rule? Being a normal clause, that depends on what information you need to pass to, and return from the call to the predicate: you must know that to be able to write the program.

Comment: By rule, I mean a normal definite clause. Thank you for the help